# Spatial join returns NULL-values

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, spatial-analyst, spatial-join

I'm trying to create a join where I take the sum of the values of one of the attributes in the point layer within each buffer and add it to the bufferlayers attribute table. I can't figure out which settings I need. Do I get all values with intersect or should i choose contains or touches? I want the aggregated value from one of the attributes within so I suppose I should take the "Attribute summary" that you can se in the picture?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you should configurate your analysis in this way:

[image]

I did a test and the output is a polygon layer which stores the sum of your point layer values in a field called `"sumVAL"` (`"VAL"` was the original field of the point layer where I stored the values to sum).

Comment: Also make sure that the two layers have the same projection. Otherwise they will still not intersect and the sums will be NULL.